# Instrumenting iOS Application in XCode - Archive Fail Error

Tags: ionic-framework, xcode7, testcomplete

I try to build .api file to test by testComplete following this link:

https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/mobile/ios/preparing/instrumenting-apps/xcode-6.html

But when I go to step archive project Xcode throw error:

> ld: library not found for -lTestComplete-agent-static clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The project is Ionic Project, I search in web but not find any clues. I think the trouble is `stepAdd the TestComplete Agent Library to Your Project` . Please help me how to archive it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, this is an issue with the settings of your project in Xcode. First of all, make sure that you specified the correct search path for the TestComplete library (see [here](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/issues/297#issuecomment-247644647)). Also, double check that you changed the build settings as [documented](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/mobile/ios/preparing/instrumenting-apps/xcode-6.html#4_Change_Build_Settings).

If this does not help, contact [SmartBear support](http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete) with details on the project settings.